# Yii CGridView - Custom Columns

Tags: php, javascript, gridview, yii

been looking for a solution to add a feature for "Custom Columns"... Meaning, I present a list of columns that I can show the user and he selects the ones he wants to see and after the selection the table is updated and add/removes the needed columns.

Didn't find anything on Google (perhaps it has a different name than what I was looking for...)

Anyone has an Idea on how it can be accomplished?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to do it with ajax, or in different pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete sample, but can give you some clues on how to implement it. You've to define some kind of form to collect the data about how your grid has to be rendered. I recommend you to create a CFormModel class if there are more than 3 input fields. Create a view file with the form and a div or renderPartial of a file containing a grid:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveFormExt');
echo $form->errorSummary($model);
echo $form->labelEx($model,'column1');
echo $form->dropDownList($model
echo $form->error($model,'column1');
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('UpdateGrid',array('controller/grid'),
                                array('update'=>'#grid'),
$this->endWidget();
// you can render the 'default options' before any ajax update
$this->renderPartial('_grid',array($customColumns=>array('id','name'),'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
```

In the _grid.php view file:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns' => $customColumns;
));
```

In the controller:

```
function actionGrid(){
    // recover the form data, and build the custom columns array
    $customColumns = array();
    $customColumns[] = '.....';

    $dataProvider = ...;

    $this->renderPartial('_formTrabajo', array('customColumns' => $idSiniestro, 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider'), false);
}
```

When you click the ajaxSubmitButton, the form is sent to the url specified through ajax, and the reply from the controller must contain the renderPartial of the view containing the grid, so the jQuery call can replace the html correctly. You must pass an array from your controller to the partial view of the grid, with the custom list of columns you want to display.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the idea.